# How to create gradient text with a clipped background

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to draw gradient text. My idea is to create a gradient using the code [from the docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/gradient_bar.html) to create a gradient background and then clip that image using a text path. For whatever reason, I'm only getting the first letter and some of the second.

[image]

Changing the limits of the axes or the width of the figure don't seem to work. I can change the size of the TextPath, but then I can't seem to make the text take up the full size of the image. Making the text size .2 and setting the ylim from 0 to .2 only makes squished text. How can I make the text span the size of the axes and take the full range of the gradient?

[image]

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties
import matplotlib.textpath
import matplotlib.patches
import numpy as np


def gradient_image(ax, extent, direction=0.3, cmap_range=(0, 1), **kwargs):
    """
    Draw a gradient image based on a colormap.

    Parameters
    ----------
    ax : Axes
        The axes to draw on.
    extent
        The extent of the image as (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax).
        By default, this is in Axes coordinates but may be
        changed using the *transform* keyword argument.
    direction : float
        The direction of the gradient. This is a number in
        range 0 (=vertical) to 1 (=horizontal).
    cmap_range : float, float
        The fraction (cmin, cmax) of the colormap that should be
        used for the gradient, where the complete colormap is (0, 1).
    **kwargs
        Other parameters are passed on to `.Axes.imshow()`.
        In particular useful is *cmap*.
    """
    phi = direction * np.pi / 2
    v = np.array([np.cos(phi), np.sin(phi)])
    X = np.array([[v @ [1, 0], v @ [1, 1]],
                  [v @ [0, 0], v @ [0, 1]]])
    a, b = cmap_range
    X = a + (b - a) / X.max() * X
    im = ax.imshow(X, extent=extent, interpolation='bicubic',
                   vmin=0, vmax=1, **kwargs)
    return im


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(1,1))

im = gradient_image(ax, direction=1, extent=(0, 1, 0, 1), transform=ax.transAxes,
               cmap=plt.cm.winter, cmap_range=(0.2, 0.8), alpha=0.5)

fp = FontProperties(family='DejaVu Sans', weight='bold')
text = matplotlib.textpath.TextPath((0.0, 0.0), 'ABCDEFG',
                                             size=1, prop=fp)

im.set_clip_path(text, transform=ax.transAxes)

# ax.set_xticks(())
# ax.set_yticks(())
# ax.tick_params(width=0, which='both')
# ax.set_xlim((0, 10))
# ax.set_ylim((0, 1))
for spine in ['top', 'bottom', 'left', 'right']:
    ax.spines[spine].set_visible(False)
```

Comment: Not the issue, but you can just do `ax.spines[['top', 'bottom', 'left', 'right']].set_visible(False)`

Comment: Apparently `ax.spines[:].set_visible(False)` also works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not fully fluent in [matplotlib transformations](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html), but from what I've read, ax.transData seems to be the better approach here (comments were I changed your code):

[image]

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties
import matplotlib.textpath
import matplotlib.patches
import numpy as np


def gradient_image(ax, extent, direction=0.3, cmap_range=(0, 1), **kwargs):
    """
    Draw a gradient image based on a colormap.

    Parameters
    ----------
    ax : Axes
        The axes to draw on.
    extent
        The extent of the image as (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax).
        By default, this is in Axes coordinates but may be
        changed using the *transform* keyword argument.
    direction : float
        The direction of the gradient. This is a number in
        range 0 (=vertical) to 1 (=horizontal).
    cmap_range : float, float
        The fraction (cmin, cmax) of the colormap that should be
        used for the gradient, where the complete colormap is (0, 1).
    **kwargs
        Other parameters are passed on to `.Axes.imshow()`.
        In particular useful is *cmap*.
    """
    phi = direction * np.pi / 2
    v = np.array([np.cos(phi), np.sin(phi)])
    X = np.array([[v @ [1, 0], v @ [1, 1]],
                  [v @ [0, 0], v @ [0, 1]]])
    a, b = cmap_range
    X = a + (b - a) / X.max() * X
    # added origin = lower, elsewise text is flipped upside down
    im = ax.imshow(X, extent=extent, interpolation='bicubic',
                   vmin=0, vmax=1, origin='lower', **kwargs)
    return im


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(1, 1))

# define text before gradient to get extent
fp = FontProperties(family='DejaVu Sans', weight='bold')
text = matplotlib.textpath.TextPath((0.0, 0.0), 'ABCDEFG',
                                    size=1, prop=fp)
# use text to define imshow extent
extent = text.get_extents().extents[[0, 2, 1, 3]]
im = gradient_image(ax, direction=1, extent=extent,
                    cmap=plt.cm.winter, cmap_range=(0.2, 0.8), alpha=0.5)

# use transData instead of transAxes
im.set_clip_path(text, transform=ax.transData)
# © trenton
ax.spines[['top', 'bottom', 'left', 'right']].set_visible(False)

plt.show()
```

Comment: I accepted it as the correct answer, but it's the 90% solution. I propose that you change setting the extent to this: `extent=(0, text.vertices[:,0].max(), 0, text.vertices[:,1].max())`

Comment: better yet, `extent=(
    text.vertices[:,0].min(), 
    text.vertices[:,0].max(), 
    text.vertices[:,1].min(), 
    text.vertices[:,1].max()),`

Comment: Yes, dynamically calculating the y-extent makes sense. I just assumed that the width of the text would always be the limiting factor, but this is surely not correct. I'll update my code accordingly

Comment: just found out that the Path (https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/path_api.html#matplotlib.path.Path) has its own get_extents() method. After a little bit of reordering, this eliminates the numpy min-max-madness.

Comment: @ChristianKarcher Do you have to do `extent = text.get_extents().extents[[0, 2, 1, 3]]` because texts and images use different "extents" conventions? I assume one is (x0, x1, y0, y1) and the other (x0, y0, x1, y1) and that forces you to change the indices.

Comment: @Guimoute yes, precisely. I guess there is no enforced "standard" for this order in matplotlib